# Integrate CMD to with a webpage

Tags: python, cmd

How to integrate cmd to webpage ??

1. Python script runs in cmd by getting a input and generates out in
       command line.
2. i need to get the input from a webpage and generates
           the out on the same page
3. i need a hint of any api or other methods
           to integrate.